# UISearch bar in Bar Button Item in Storyboard can't be clicked

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, xcode-storyboard

I add a Navigation bar and for the left bar item I set the `UIView`. Inside the view, I add a search bar.

[image]

It looks ok, but it is "disabled". It is not white and I can't click on it:

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you given the constraints to the search bar? I tried with flexible space bar button item, it works seamlessly.

Comment: And also make sure that the navigation bar is not outside the safe area. Apple suggests that we do not place any controls outside the safe area